# Life is where my heart is - "where" in the right place?

Tags: word-usage, inversion

Have I used the word "where" in the right place in the following sentence?

> Life is where my heart is.

Comment: [♫ *But home is where the heart is / so your real home's in your chest!* ♫](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dr_horrible)

Comment: @snailboat +1 for the Dr. Horrible reference. :-)

Comment: "Life is **wherever** my heart is" I think sounds better and avoids anyone confusing it with the proverb, "Home is where the heart is".

Answer (score 1):

If you literally mean that the location of the mentioned life is in your heart, which means you can find life within your heart..
Then I don't think this is a wrong sentence, it's grammatically perfect.

Different opinion would count if you meant *another thing* other than that.

Answer (score 1):

Your sentence sounds strange to me. I think there are two reasons:

1) As @snailboat pointed out, there is a saying in English:

> Home is where the heart is.

I think your sentence is too close to this saying, and it sounds like you misremembered the saying.

2) I'm not 100% sure what idea you're trying to convey. You could be trying to say any of the following:

> My life is important to me.
>   What's important in my life are the things I love
>   I have dedicated myself to having a fulfilling/interesting/important life.

Comment: Perhaps the intended meaning is that one makes a life for oneself in the place (town/country) where one's heart is, i.e. where one's beloved happens to live. It seems like an intended extension of the more familiar "Home is where the heart is" to cover the idea that one ought not merely have a home in that place but also engage with truly making a life there.

Comment: @toandfro Good point... I hadn't thought of that interpretation.

Comment: @toandfro I agree with your interpretation.